# Installing floyd-cli on windows

Tags: python

I have tried installing `floyd-cli` on Windows and I get the following result:

[image: floyd-cli installation result]

And when I enter the command below:

`floyd --help`

it says `floyd is not recognized as internal or external command`.

How should `floyd-cli` be installed on Windows?